# EditText keeps outdated size

Tags: android, xml

I have an `EditText` view in my `RelativeLayout`. It wraps around its content quite nicely besides one thing. I've set the `android:hint` attribute to some default text and whenever some text is entered, which has less width than the hint, the box doesn't wrap. It stays there as it would wrap around the hint-text. Using the `android:text` attribute instead is no option, as you'd need to delete every character which would be very annoying. I've attached three pictures and the XML, both are following.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="@string/textEditDefaultText"
    android:background="#4b010101"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Here it should be smaller, you can clearly see it at the right part of the `EditText`. [image]

Or more clear but with more text:

[image]

As seen here, it wraps properly when the text is longer.
[image]

I'm using Android 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using either a custom EditText or a TextWatcher to call requestLayout() each time the text is changed?

I'm reasonably sure though that the EditText won't shrink along the horizontal if you're using two or more lines though.

Why do you want the EditText to change width anyways? Maybe there's a different solution?

Comment: Not want to be rough but I'm seeking for an answer, not for another three questions. If you have a lack of information to answer my question properly, please suggest a change in the comment section of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this a bug. The hint shouldn't be part of the layout at all

> The hint does not currently participate in determining the size of the view. 
>   ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29))

Comment: Thank you, I've posted a bug report at the repository after I weren't able to find an issue similar to this: [report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=184039)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to be a bug, as F43nd1r suggested. I've filed a request accordingly [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=184039). However, we can write a quick and dirty fix for this by hacking a custom view together. So creating a new Java class, XML file and using the custom `EditText` as replacement for the normal `EditText` fixed the issue.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    public CharSequence hint = null;

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,
                              int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        if(hint == null) {
            hint = this.getHint();
            this.setHint("");
        } else {
            if(this.getText().length == 0) {
                this.setHint(hint);
                hint = null;
            }
        }

        this.requestLayout();
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
    }
}
```

XML file located in your `layouts` folder:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <thoughts.dasnacl.thoughts.CustomEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]